# How do I append submenus to an existing FlexNativeMenu instance?

Tags: apache-flex, menu, air, adobe

I'm completely confused by this. An Adobe Flex `WindowedApplication` has a 'menu' property, which by default is assigned a `FlexNativeMenu` instance, which is used to create a native menu tree for the application.

For example, on OS X, if I create a `WindowedApplication`, I get the standard 'application menu', 'File', 'Edit' and 'Window' menus created on startup.

The question is, how do I *append* additional menus to this without creating an entirely new menu? I want to use the default OS X menus as a starting point and add my own.

If I assign `menu = new FlexNativeMenu;` I just get a completely empty application bar with no menus at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to work differently for Windows and Mac OS.  My code looks something like this:

```
if (isWindows)
{
   // Windows lacks a menu by default, create one.
   menu = new NativeMenu();
}
else if (isMac)
{
   // Mac OS has a default menu, get a reference to it.
   menu = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu;
}

buildMenu(menu);
```

The `buildMenu()` function then does a bunch of work to build the menu.

```
function buildMenu(menu:NativeMenu):NativeMenu
{
    var menuItem:NativeMenuItem = menu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Menu Label"));
    var menuItem.name = "menuLabelName";
    var menuItem.data = myDataForThisMenuItem;
    menuItem.subMenu = buildSubMenu();

    return menu;
}

function buildSubMenu():NativeMenu
{
    var subMenu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
    var menuItem:NativeMenuItem;

    menuItem = subMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Sub Menu Label"));
    menuItem.name = "subMenuName";
    menuItem.data = subMenuData;

    return subMenu;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, except that assigning `menu = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu` gives the following complier error: **Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:NativeMenu to an unrelated type mx.controls:FlexNativeMenu.** Any ideas?

Comment: The type for `menu` should be `NativeMenu` not `FlexNativeMenu`.

Comment: Sure, but the `menu` property of `WindowedApplication` has type `FlexNativeMenu` and there's nothing I can do about that. However, I'm starting to think the right way to solve this is to ignore `WindowedApplication.menu` altogether and construct the menu as you describe, using e.g. `myMenu = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu` as a starting point.

Comment: Don't have my code accessible right now but I'm pretty sure that's what I'm doing.